# HP ProLiant DL360 G5 fails to reboot

Tags: hardware, hp, boot, hp-proliant

Some history of this also available [here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ITRC-ProLiant-deployment/HP-proliant-dl360-G5-fails-rebooting/td-p/5855033#.UJ-O8GfPbTo).

As of my latest update on the forum linked above, now cold reboot as well as hard reset and following boot for my proliant dl360 g5 works as expected and successfully boot the system.

However, soft-reboot results in internal health indicator turning RED on the front and long beeps every around 6seconds until I either cold reboot or press and hold the power button.

A summary of system state when this happens:

- Internal Health led indicator: RED
- External Health led indicator: Green
- No led next to any component is red or amber
- No POST message neither on the video output nor on IML logs (verified both at the time issue occures and after cold reboot that boots the system successfully).

Any thoughts please share. I hope we can knock this issue down together with your help!

Comment: I'd call HP support and ask them to kindly fix/replace their shit ASAP.  Do you not have a warranty or support contract on this box?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure on that. This system has a bit of history for its owners.And since it's a bit old system calling HP support does not look much promising to me - though I may try to find out at latest what the case is.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're trying to troubleshoot a circa 2006-2008 server that's fallen outside of its normal hardware warranty...

Internal health LED means just that. Internal health. Could be RAM, system board, CPU/CPU socket. You're also at the age where the system board battery could use a refresh. Nowhere in your post here did I see any indication of opening the server and reseating the components. Normally, that's the first step.

Now, outside of that, I recommended that you download the *bootable* [HP Firmware DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) and run it on the system [in your previous question](https://serverfault.com/a/444850/13325). Did you do this?

If all else fails, you can call HP and talk to a tech. I don't know if you're in the US, so I won't post a direct number... but you can usually get fairly far in phone troubleshooting... but still, they'll ask you to update your firmware. So please do that first.

Edit:

You said that you received several of these old servers at the same time. Try swapping components or booting with a minimal set of components. One CPU, 1 or 2 DIMMs to start. And work up from there. At a certain point, though, how much is your time worth? This is a server that [can be found for < $200US on the used market](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Servers-/11211/i.html?_udlo=50&_dcat=11211&LH_BIN=1&Brand=HP&_from=R40&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udhi=500&_nkw=dl360%20g5&_sop=12). If there's a problem with it, get a different one.

Comment: Of course I've done all that before writting. Firmware is all up-to-date. I also verified that all components are well reseated. Please note that except this issue the system is running well as well as all the diagnostic tests are passing well - even the lengthy ones from smartstart. Is there a way to verify the cmos battery health?

Comment: See edit. Try swapping a known-good battery in place.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking on HP's WWW site, e.g.: [HP POST Beep Codes](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c01702138).  From my experience, I'd be re-seating the CPU and RAM before considering swapping parts...